# How to change "All Categories" Text Language Dropdown Search Box Filter in Magento

Tags: magento, search, categories

I want to change language "All Categories" Tree in Search Filter Box. I can't find any locale files, js, css or any html file.

I try magento translate system but miss out this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E02dM.jpg

Comment: Check if the text is not hard coded (non translatable) in the phtml file. Turn on template path hints to see which template uses it.

Comment: look all phtml files now but i cant find anything:(

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem and have some findings. Let me share here, while it might/might not be exactly the location for your case.

Magento put its translation several places:

- translation_name.csv in `%magento_root%\app\locale\{locale such as en_US}`
- configuration value in Admin such as `configuration -> catalog -> Category Top Navigation -> Prefix for Links in dropdown`
- Category Name is in Manage Category, just select their corresponding Language in store view can do, uncheck the global or Website beside the name to use the individual(local) settings instead.

There is a tutorial/explanation quite comprehensive from search that you may refer to http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/multilingual-store

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the text in search header from all categories to anything else you have to create CSV file and then put in it this: "All Categories", "To whatever you want to change the text".
Here is a link that will help you to create a CSV file: https://www.atwix.com/magento/create-csv-files/